# replication tab missing on php my admin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am having an issue setting the php my admin database up as a master slave. I am developing locally and want to set up the server database as a slave. There is an option to replicate the database in php myadmin in the localhost php myadmin area. When I log into the server cpanel php myadmin the replication tab is missing so I can not finish the configuration. Does anybody know the best way to configure a local;host database as a master and the server database as the slave if the server php myadmin doesn't have a replication tab

Answer (score 1):

**It took me a few minutes to find it as well...**
In October of 2020 I'm seeing the Replication tab in phpMyAdmin when focused on the server. Best way to get there is to click the HOME icon as indicated in the image below.
[image: phpMyAdmin]

***Version info*:**
**Database server**
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used
Server version: 5.7.32-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10

**Web server**
cpsrvd xx.xx.xx.xx
Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43
PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring
PHP version: 7.3.6
**phpMyAdmin**
Version information: 4.9.5

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an older version of phpmyadmin. I had the some problem yesterday. You will find the replication information under the "Status" tab and than the [replication] link, which will take you to the bottom of the same page.

I found the following short video helpful to understand the basics:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfsmnx24gxU

I edited the my.ini file of the MySQL (master) server by hand to include the following lines in the Master section:

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
log_error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=<your_database_to_replicate>
```

If you want to replicate the entire server, than you can omit the last line. Or alternatively, if you want to replicate all but certain databases than for each of those db you add:

```
binlog_ignore_db=<your_database_not_to_replicate>
```

As you can see from the following screen shot, my server is running. Unfortunately, although I have been able to connect my client database, the replication has not started. I will update this answer, once I resolved it, but maybe this will be enough for you to solve your problem or even mine.

[image]

Btw, it may be helpful for others if you can state your MySQL and phpMyAdmin versions. I am using 5.0.10 and 3.2.4, respectively.